# Duplicate output from Webpack

Tags: webpack

In my webpack config file I have the usual output config:

```
output: {
  path: buildPath,
  filename: 'scripts/boundle.min.js'
}
```

However I want one output at `/build` (`buildPath`) and another to a folder where I have Cordova settings. Currently I have to copy-paste `/build` to Cordova but I want Webpack to output two duplicated outputs instead at two different paths. Is this possible?

## Solution

I already have some plugins that I'm already running when building for production (such as `UglifyJsPlugin`) so I implemented [bebraw's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36116140/4826084) solution in an if-statement:

```
if (production) {
  configForCordova = _.assign({}, config)
  configForCordova.output = {
    path: buildPathCordova,
    filename: 'scripts/boundle.min.js'
  }
  module.exports = [config, configForCordova]
} else {
  module.exports = config
}
```

I'm just building for production once or twice per week so it's no problem that it's slow. `&&` is not very Windows-friendly. It only seems to be working on W10.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One convoluted way to achieve this within webpack would be to write configuration like this:

```
...

module.exports = [config1, config2]; // alter output per config
```

The problem is that it will run webpack twice and this is going to be slow.

Consider handling this outside of webpack. You can deal with it easily within `package.json` **scripts**. E.g. `"build": "webpack && cp -rf build cordova_build"`.

Comment: For some reason not all plugins are running when using webpack multi-compiler. I use `HtmlWebpackPlugin` to build my `index.html` from `index.template` but for some reason only the first config in the array (ie config1 in your example) gets the index.html. Any ideas why that is?

Comment: @Oskar Unfortunately the configurations are treated separately in this case so using `HtmlWebpackPlugin` might not work that well.

Comment: @beraw But `HtmlWebpackPlugin` is present in both configurations so I don't understand why it's not working? Have I misunderstood something about Webpack or the plugins?

Comment: @Oskar You can treat the array syntax as the same as if you ran webpack twice and passed a different configuration file to it. I would need something to run to debug further.

Comment: Then it should work, the configs are identical except from the output. Or at least they should be. A did a lazy comparison with `JSON.stringy(config1) === JSON.stringy(config2)` before changing the output. My `webpack.config.js` is [here](https://github.com/OskarKlintrot/1dv411-project/blob/dev/webpack.config.js), together with the rest of the project. I have commented out the code for duplicating the output.

Comment: You should rename `index.template` as `index.template.ejs`. Otherwise it won't output `index.html` and you get just `index.template` instead. If you have time, set up a minimal test case and report it [upstream](https://github.com/ampedandwired/html-webpack-plugin).

Comment: Thanks, now it is working! Even though I still get the template in the build.

Comment: @Oskar Ok. Please write a simple test case illustrating the issue and push the problem upstream so we get it fixed. :)

Comment: Should I do it as an issue or how do you want it?

Comment: @Oskar Develop a repository showing the problem (minimal amount of code) and link that to a GitHub issue so it's easy to debug.

Answer (score 2):

Just add a second entry with a different name but the same source file. Then you can have as many output files as you want:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        foo: 'bar.js',
        foo2: 'bar.js',
        '../path/to/dist': 'bar.js'
    },

    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'public'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
    }
};
```

Comment: Won't they end up in the same folder?

Comment: The key is a relative link. Look at my third entry and you’ll see I’m putting a copy in a parallel folder called dist rather than in public. That folder could be a soft link to anywhere

Comment: Ah, sorry! Good answer then! Unfortunately I can't try it out but at least I can give you an upvote.